# Facebook login is not working correctly for another person

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am doing log in facebook using facebook sdk in my application in which authorize person (through which I have created example on facebook) doing log in successfully but when another person doing log in then he is not able to log in (I think session is created but session state is closed) now I am confused what I do.
my code is below

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "deepak";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    Boolean isInternetPresent;
    private TextView albumTextView;
    private static String APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    Facebook facebook;
    Session session;
    private boolean flag = false;
    static ArrayList<String> allNames;
    static  ArrayList<String> uid;
    static ArrayList<String> picUrl;

//    String[] pics =  new String[]{};
//    String[] uids;
//    String[] allnames;

    JSONArray jArray;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
         LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
         authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("read_friendlists", "user_photos", "friends_photos"));
         albumTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_viet_albul);
         authButton.setFragment(this);
         facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
         allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
         uid = new ArrayList<String>();
         picUrl = new ArrayList<String>();

         ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity()); 
         isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
         checkInternetConnection();

         return view;
    }

    private void checkInternetConnection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!isInternetPresent) {                    
            // Internet connection is not present                     
            // Ask user to connect to Internet                    
            showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection", "You don't have internet connection.", false);                
            } 
        }


     public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();          
         // Setting Dialog Title         
         alertDialog.setTitle(title);           
         // Setting Dialog Message         
         alertDialog.setMessage(message);                   
         // Setting alert dialog icon         
         //alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);           
         // Setting OK Button         
         alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
         {            
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
             {    
                 MainActivity.finishIfNetworkIsNotWorking();
             }        
         });           
         // Showing Alert Message         
         alertDialog.show();     

     }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");

        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
        {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
       uiHelper.onResume();       
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }
}
```

Comment: when in i debugg then it goes inside  else if (state.isClosed()) {
         Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        
     }   in  onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)  and logged out not log in...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you do log out when you change user? Sometimes your tokens or session is saving in share preferences, and when you run your app it load tokens from file and create your session.
Your method log out must be like next:

```
 private void onClickLogout() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}
```

Do you get active session?

Comment: and when you log in with another user what is happens?

Comment: when another user doing log in then this part of program run  it goes inside else if (state.isClosed()) { Log.i(TAG, "Logged out..."); } in onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) and logged out not log in...)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

after you get the enough details or process is done with the logged in account. So when login  again it automatically looks for a new Token from facebook user.

Comment: try calling it in ondestroy.